# Looking for a regex can that pull the list of all the cmdlets used inside a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am doing something like this:

```
$ScriptContent = get-content "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scripts\SFB.ps1"
$ScriptContent -match '(?<N>.*)-(?<V>.*)'
```

Comment: take a look at the AST stuff. powershell can make the entire Abstract Syntax Tree available to examine.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to identify command invocations in PowerShell is a lost cause, consider just hooking straight into [the parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser) engine instead (see inline comments):

```
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scripts\SFB.ps1"

# Parse the script
$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile((Resolve-Path $scriptPath).ProviderPath, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)

# Now we use the AST to find all command invocations
#AST.FindAll({
  $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst]
}, $true) |ForEach-Object {
  # The first element is always the name
  $command = $_.CommandElements[0]

  # if the command name is a constant string, resolve it's value
  if($command -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst]){
    $commandName = $command.Value
    $known = $true
  } else {
    # Otherwise, note that the name can only be known at runtime
    $commandName = "'{0}'" -f $command.Extent
    $known = $false
  }

  # output new object with the information
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = $commandName
    Constant = $known
    File = $scriptPath
    Line = $command.Extent.StartLineNumber
  }
}
```

If your script looks like this:

```
Get-Process

& "Get-Service"

$a = "Get-Item"

. $a 'C:\Windows'
```

You should expect the following output:

```
Name        Constant File                                   Line
----        -------- ----                                   ----
Get-Process     True C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scripts\SFB.ps1    1
Get-Service     True C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scripts\SFB.ps1    3
'$a'           False C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scripts\SFB.ps1    7
```